# How do i get items in a listbox that is in another Form

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 2 Form in my project Form1 and Form2

I have to get items in a Listbox1 in Form2 when initializing in Form1.

Here is the code in Form1:

```
private void OnRosterItem(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.iq.roster.RosterItem item)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new XmppClientConnection.RosterHandler(OnRosterItem), new object[] { this, item });
            return;
        }
        if (item.Subscription == SubscriptionType.both)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (item.Jid.ToString() == listBox1.Items[i].ToString())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Remove(item.Jid);
                }
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add(item.Jid.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This Listbox1 is in Form2 how to get the items there.

Thank you

Comment: @gkrishy, OP talking about WINFORM. Where does the session concept coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be making a `List` and passing the contents of `Form1` to `Form2` through [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx), and then populate the `Listbox` with the passed contents.

In `Form2` constructor:

```
public MainWindow(List<string> Values)
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    foreach(var row in Values){
        Listbox1.Items.Add(row);
    }
}
```

In `Form1` when calling `Form2`:

```
List<string> Values = new List<string>();
Values.Add("I'm a row!");
Values.Add("So am I!");
var form = new Form2();
form.Show(Values);
```

The `Listbox` will then contain the following items by following my example:

- I'm a row!
- So am I!

If you want to populate the `List` when you create it, you can simply do the following:

```
var Values = new List<string> { "I'm a row!", "So am I!" };
```

This produces the same result as above with just one line instead of three.

Comment: the items in listbox are not user specific.///it contains data from server that is fed by server.so cannot fill the values there.

Comment: You can still do the same, get the data from the server before opening Form2, just populate the List while doing so and then call Form2.

Comment: can you elaborate please.

Comment: The code i mentioned can generate list items in the same form.i want item list in listbox1 that is in Form2.

Comment: This was very elaborated already...you get the data from the server, while reading through it you add each row you get from there to the List like I showed above, and then you pass it to Form2, I don't think I can be more elaborate than this.

Comment: can you  tell me how to transfer a listbox items in a listbox in form1 to a listbox in form2//i hope it would be simple for me if i create  2 Listbox.one in form1 and other in form2.then i open form2 with a button click the list items in listbox of form1 gets tranferred in listbox of form2.